# Elasticsearch Boost near location, boost if no location is available

Tags: elasticsearch

There is Location field exists with geo_point type

I want to implement with some conditions below.

1. If there is a location, the closer it is, boost it
2. If there is no location, boost by 5

Ultimately, i want to implement the following features: If the location exists, will show it in the order of distance, but we would like to boost documents without location so that they are not pushed out last.

below is my query. I reached to get nearest document by location. But i don't know how to boost which is no location.

```
{
 "query": {
  "bool": {
   "must": {
        "match_all": {}
  },
  "should": {
      "distance_feature": {
          "field": "location",
          "pivot": "1000m",
          "boost": 8,
          "origin": {
              "lat": 33.489009,
              "lon": 133.022831
          }
      }
  },
  "filter": [
    {
        "terms" : {
            "state": ["AVAILABLE"]
        }
    }
 ]
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do it like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "minimum_should_match": 1, 
      "should": [
        {
          "distance_feature": {
            "field": "locations.parcelLocation",
            "pivot": "1000m",
            "boost": 8,
            "origin": {
              "lat": 33.489009,
              "lon": 133.022831
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": {
              "exists": {
                "field": "location",
                "boost": 5
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "state": [
              "AVAILABLE"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: must_not exists location boosting seems not working. location which is null still pushed out last.

Comment: Well, since you have most of your documents with a location and a constant 8x boost, it's to be expected.

Comment: yes. most of documents has location. but It's the same even if i increase the boost.

Comment: The solution would be to leverage geo_distance sorting, but that doesn't support documents without location.

Comment: But why is must_not exist field boosting is not working? I set explain true to see explanation, but boosting is not applied.

Comment: Boosting cannot apply to must_not since the document does NOT exist, so it cannot be boosted :-)